# i cant update a innerhtml in a js for loop with ajax it only updates the last loop in whole loop how to fix this?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

my js file
`

```
var rows = 8

function shoplist() {
    for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        var getdate = getdatedata.value;
    var outsub = document.createElement("button");
    var outsubh1 = document.createElement("h1");
    var outsubh2 = document.createElement("h1");
    outsub.setAttribute("id", "outsubs");
    outsubh1.setAttribute("class", "shopname");
    outsubh2.setAttribute("class", "allprice");
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        method: "post",
        data: {"getdate" : getdate},
        success: function(res) {
            console.log(res);
            outsubh1.innerHTML = res;
        }
    })
    outsubh2.innerHTML = "okk"+i;
    outsub.appendChild(outsubh1);
    outsub.appendChild(outsubh2);
    out.appendChild(outsub);
    }
}
```

`

my php file
`

```
<?php
  include "connection.php";
  $getdate = $_POST["getdate"];
  echo $getdate;
?>
```

`

the thing is it is consolelogging 8 times perfectly but not updating innerhtml 8 times

pls help me in this

thank you

i expected to update innerhtml 8 times whole loop but it only updates to the last one in loop

Comment: Do all the DOM manipulations in `success`. Notice, that you're creating multiple elements with the same id. This id is useless, either drop it, or add a dynamic part to the value.

Comment: sir do i need to create elements and edit elements in success? @Teemu

Comment: You can create the elements in the body of the loop, but you've to declare the variables with `const` or `let` instead of `var`. All the code adding data fetched by the AJAX call should be in `success` (practically everything what is currently placed after `$.ajax(...);`).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing a mistake here.

The outsubh1 heading is reinitialised on each iteration of loop.
And the loop is only printing the last value, because on each new iteration of loop the previous iteration values are overwritten.

I mean i think you should initialize it outside the loop, and use the append() function, to append the value.

```js
document.body.onload = shoplist;
function shoplist() {
    var rows = 8;
    var temp = document.getElementById("temp");
    for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    var htmlCode = "<button id='outsubs_"+i+"'>"+"button "+ i +"</button><br>"+ "heading outsubh1 " + i +"<h1 class='shopname'></h1>"+ "heading outsubh2 " + i + "<h1 class='shopname'>  </h1>";
    //temp.appendChild(htmlCode);
    $("#temp").append(htmlCode);

    //$.ajax({
      //  url: "test.php",
      //  method: "post",
      //  data: {"getdate" : getdate},
      //  success: function(res) {
      //      //place the htmlCode here, and make set your response accordingly
      //      outsubh1.innerHTML = res;
      //  }
    // })
    
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="temp"> </div>
```

In the above code, each button has different id. And we are appending each iteration after the div (with id = "temp").

You can do it like this also, I have used a little bit jquery.
You have to place the htmlCode in ajax response, and can set your response accordingly.